# cloning a repo from github

Tags: git, github

I trying to clone this repo, but I can't get the bash command line correctly:

https://github.com/google/android-ui-toolkit-demos/tree/master/RecyclerView/RecyclerViewAnimations

according to this thread there should be  URL button, but I can't find it.

https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/

where is the .git file?

thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to clone the entire repo, not just the folder. From command line, do `git clone https://github.com/google/android-ui-toolkit-demos.git`

Answer (score 0):

Open the repository and you will see the link on the button (SSH in the image)

[image]

[image]

If you did not set ssh keys so you will only see `http/https`

[image]

Copy the user, open `git-bash` and clone it :

```
git clone <url>
```